# Who can explain nodejs promises in a loop to a PHP programmer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have searched high and low but can't get my head around promises. What I do understand is how to define one promise and use its result by using .then.

What I do not understand is how I can create a loop to query the database for different blocks of records. This is needed due to a limit set on the number of records to query.

The predefined promise api call is used like this:

```
let getRecords = (name) => {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    xyz.api.getRecords(name, 1000, 1000, function(err, result){
      // result gets processed here.
    resolve(//somevariables here);
    });
)};
```

going with what I am used to, I tried:

```
for (let i=1; i<90000; i+=500) {
    xyz.api.getRecords('james', i, 500, function(err, result){
      // result gets processed here.
    });
}
```

But then I can't access the information (could be my wrong doing)
Also tried something like this:

```
function getRecords(name,i){
        xyz.api.getRecords(name, i, 500, function(err, result){
          // result gets processed here.
        });
};

for (let i=1; i<90000; i+=500) {
       var someThing = getRecords('james', i);
}
```

All tutorials only seem to use one query, and process the data.

How do I call the api function multiple times with different arguments, collect the data and process it once everything is retrieved?
Only thing I can think of is, to write info to a file, terrible thought.

Comment: There is not even one `Promise` in your code. `xyz.api.getRecords` uses callback

Comment: You can write pseudo-synchronous code by using `async` and `await` keywords!

Comment: @ponury-kostek more code is added.

Comment: @RST You change `getRecords` to return `Promise`, but still use `xyz.api.getRecords` in first loop

Comment: @ponury-kostek I am a php programmer who got a nodejs job thrown on his desk. The first bit of code is the original code. The function is called in a Promise.all(). The problem is that it queries from record 1 to 5000, but there are more records, the limit to retrieve is 5000. So I need to find a way to make it loop and start taking in account records 5001 to 10000 and so on also.

The other functions are just things I tried.

Comment: See code snippet in my answer

Comment: Check out [Up and Running with Asynchronous JavaScript](https://medium.com/@rcepeda1993/async-js-the-complete-guide-670b4cf906c6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `async`/`await`

```
(async () => {
    function getRecords(name,i){
        // create new Promise so you can await for it later
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
            xyz.api.getRecords(name, i, 500, function(err, result){
                if(err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                resolve(result);
            });
        });

    }
    for (let i = 1; i < 90000; i += 500) {
        // wait for the result in every loop iteration
        const someThing = await getRecords('james', i); 
    }
})();
```

To handle errors you need to use `try/catch` block

```
try {
    const someThing = await getRecords('james', i);
} catch(e) {
    // handle somehow
}
```

Using only `Promise`s

```
function getRecords(name, i) {
    // create Promise so you can use Promise.all
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
        xyz.api.getRecords(name, i, 500, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}

const results = [];
for (let i = 1; i < 90000; i += 500) {
    // push Promise's to array without waiting for results
    results.push(getRecords("james", i));
}
// wait for all pending Promise's
Promise.all(results).then((results) => { 
    console.log(results);
});
```

```js
let count = 0;

function getRecords(name, i) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
   // example results
   resolve((new Array(10)).fill(0).map(() => ++count));
  }, 100);
 });
}

const results = [];
for (let i = 1; i < 9000; i += 500) {
 results.push(getRecords("james", i));
}
Promise.all(results).then((results) => {
 console.log("Results:", results);
  console.log("Combined results:",[].concat(...results));
});
```

To handle errors you need to use `.catch()` block

```
Promise.all(results).then((results) => { ... }).catch((error) => {
    // handle somehow
});
```

Comment: Almost. I know it was a mistake from OP's code but this will never exit the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks I got it running for one name. My next challenge will be to make it work for an array of names.

Answer (score -3):

By returning a promise and calling your asynchronous function inside, you can `resolve` the result and then use it this way:

```
function getRecords (name, i) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        xyz.api.getRecords(name, i, 500, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
}

for (let i = 1; i < 90000; i * 500) {
    getRecords('james', i)
        .then(result => {
            // do stuff with result
        })
}
```

Or, using `async` / `await` syntax:

```
async function getRecords (name, i) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        xyz.api.getRecords(name, i, 500, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
}

// this needs to happen inside a function, node does not allow top level `await`
for (let i = 1; i < 90000; i *= 500) {
    const result = await getRecords('james', i);
    // do stuff
}
```

Get all of your records at once

```
const requests = [];
for (let i = 1; i < 90000; i * 500) {
    requests.push(getRecords('james', i));
}
const results = await Promise.all(requests);
```